# summing row values in multi-index table using python

Tags: python, pandas

I tried getting an extra column (Total) of the sum of all occurences of '1' from the dataframe below. Dataframe has multiindex columns (ID,Effect and Duration).

```
ID  Effect  Duration    X1  X2  X3  
1888    High    5   1   0   1
1313    High    10  0   1   0
3455    Low 20  1   0   0
```

my cmd:

```
df['Total'] = df[df.columns].sum(1)
```

This gave me an unexpected values in the 'Total' column.

Obtained output:

```
ID  Effect  Duration    X1  X2  X3  Total   
1888    High    5   1   0   1   11
1313    High    10  0   0   0   0
3455    Low 20  1   1   1   111
```

Desired output:

```
ID  Effect  Duration    X1  X2  X3  Total   
1888    High    5   1   0   1   2
1313    High    10  0   0   0   0
3455    Low 20  1   1   1   3
```

How can I obtain my desired output using python? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your columns are strings and not integers. Convert first the columns to the appropriate type before doing your operation:

```
df[['X1', 'X2', 'X3']].astype(int).sum(1)
```

Comment: If it is indexed correctly, then `df.astype(int).sum(1)` should suffice.

Comment: I think that either OP has the issue I mention by looking at the numbers, or it is executing other code that what is described and the question has to be closed or changed.

Comment: Regardless, to achieve what is desired, if indeed the index is a (ID,Effect and Duration) multiindex, then no need to specify the columns if you want all of them...

Comment: All your points are valid, I'm just answering OP's intention, and intention here is to explicitly mention the columns as filters.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the *intention*.

Comment: Then post your own answer, that's what SO is for!

Comment: My point is that it doesn't have anything to do with the question being asked, but generally, if there is a non-sensical redundancy, it is good to point that out in your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments and codes guys. Your codes work for me. I really appreciate it!